# UTF-8 File is not showing Chinese characters in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, encoding, utf-8, chinese

I am creating a CSV file with UTF-8 encoding.

It displays the Chinese characters properly if I open it using Notepad++.

It displays the Chinese characters properly if I open it using Notepad.

But, if I open it using Excel, I see garbage values.

If I open it using Notepad and press Control+S and close the file and reopen in Excel, it shows the characters perfectly.

Any clues whats going here?

I also tried to create a normal CSV file which has Encoding GB2312. I then used Unix command iconv to convert the file from "GB2312" to "UTF-8"

This command removes all the Chinese characters and shows only English characters. So, this is not a solution.

Please suggest.

Edit -

It doesn't show Garbage value, but shows ANSI encoding. Why does it picks ANSI encoding by default. And why after opening the same file in Notepad/Notepad++ it opens up with UTF-8.

Also, why just Control+s makes it open in Excel correctly.

Comment: For future reference: when using `iconv`, see the option `--add-signature` to add the BOM.

Answer (score 3):

In Linux UTF8 is usually saved without [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) since UTF8 BOM is optional, thus apps might have problem detecting proper encoding. You can try to save them in UTF8 with BOM or use UTF16 instead.

Comment: The problem for me was - I do not have any option to add data in UTF16 format in my programming language. Only UTF-8 is allowed and that goes without BOM.

Answer (score 0):

I was aware of BOM sequence with UTF-8 encoding but was not aware of how to add it in my file.

Now, the BOM sequence is 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF, so I tried add this as plain text but it didn't worked. So, I added the ASCII values of these to my CSV and it works.

ASCII value is =

new.text = chr$(239) & chr$(187) & chr$(191) |Concatenated

Simply add this as 1st line and it works!

Thanks Chris for your suggestion.